# The button remains pressed after clicking on "ok" or "cancel" in tk_messagebox

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit, tkmessagebox

I am using the `tk_messageBox` for an `ok-cancel` pop-up info message. The message appears when pressing on a certain button `Run`, yet after clicking on `ok` or `cancel` in the pop up info message the `Run` button is kept pressed (as illustrated in the image attached ) though enabled you can click it on it again normally. I want it to be back to normal not pressed this way ?

[image: depressed button]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are running a task in the foreground without processing UI updates, which are required in order for the *look* of the button to be updated. You probably ought to configure the Run button to be disabled (`-state disabled`) and to run `update` immediately afterwards to get the UI to be synched with the internal state (you set the button state to disabled so that you don't get multiple clicks processing at once). Then, once the task finishes, you set the state back to normal.

It's not really all that complicated, but it's much easier if you have a helper procedure, perhaps like this:

```
proc doProcessing {} {
    .runButton configure -state disabled
    update
    doTheLongProcessing
    .runButton configure -state normal
}

button .runButton -text Run -command {
    if {[tk_messageBox -type okcancel -message "is it ok?"] eq "ok"} {
        doProcessing
    }
}
pack .runButton
```